# How to identify classes covered in test class in the eclipse plugin Winter 14

Tags: ide, unit-test, eclipse

Is there a way I can see what classes do a test class cover on the eclipse plugin. I really don't like the way the Developer Console works and its super buggy and slow.

I'm looking for detailed information about what test class covers each controller/trigger.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default in the force IDE in eclipse, when you run a test class, the results shows you all the classes that were touched and covered by your class.  It shows all classes, even the ones that weren't covered by your class at all.

This is somewhat detailed, as you can drill into each class and see which lines of a particular class weren't covered.  See the screenshot below of the results after running a test class.

**Results**

[image]

**Drill Down**

[image]

Comment: Is there a way I can see which test class was involved in that ApexClass coverage?

Comment: In this case, I ran the test on one specific test class by right clicking and choosing force -> run tests.  In the case of running multiple tests, no it doesn't indicate which test class invoked the code.

Comment: hmmm ok, so whats the best advice on this thing? I need to have a way to be able to see the overall coverage for each class/trigger as a function of all test classes in the org.

Comment: Unfortunately, I believe you'll need the dev console for that.  Someone please correct me if I'm wrong.  I'm not the biggest fan either, but SF is really trying to push the dev community towards it.